# Help need, Tables jumps to next page

Tags: tables

I'm a new to LaTex. I'm trying to make my CV using Latex. I used tables. But when I use table, it jumps to next page instead keeping continuous with others. Here is my script,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\centerline{\huge\textsc{My Name}}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{Contact Information}\\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}ll}
            Name &: &\\
            Address&: & \\
            Tel&: & \\
            Email &:& \href{Email}{Email}
        \end{tabular}\\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        \textbf{Personal Information}\\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}ll}
            Date of Birth & : &\\
            Nationality & : & \\
            Sex & : & \\
            Marital State & : &\\
        \end{tabular}

    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\
\vspace{1cm}
\hfill
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{12.5cm}}
        &\\
        \textbf{EDUCATION} & \\
        \hline
        &\\
        Date & \textbf{Master} \\
        & University\\

        &\\
        Date & \textbf{Bachelor} \\
        & University\\
        &\\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE}}\\
        \hline
        &\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
        &\\
        Period& \textbf{Designation}\\
        & Company\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks you in advance

Comment: A table is a float.  It is supposed to jump around.  If you don't want it to jump around, don't use it.  It's not like you have a caption or list of tables.

Comment: Thanks, The table jumps to next page. I want to have it like in Ms word. In the code, it makes a huge space between two tables.

Comment: So you want it to break at the end of the page?  Use the longtable package.

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages for float placement:

Take a look at [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)
.